# Paramiko ssh.close() issue with multiple clients

Tags: python-3.6, paramiko

I have an interesting issue with Paramiko. I am using it for SSHClient in my code, where I test connection first then connect(always to the same host) and finally execute a task. It all works very well, and even when running it at the same time, except in 1 particular scenario. Let's say I have 2 tasks, first one takes 2 minutes to finish and second one takes 5 minutes. If I run them at the same time, but only in this order - I start 2 minute task first and then while this one is running I start a 5 minute one; Upon finish of the 2 minute task, both tasks are finished, that is the 5 minute one gets cut off. I suspect the issue is with ssh.close() which closes both sessions, as well as their underlying transport. I do use threading and call SSH function as a separate threads, but that doesn't seem to make much difference.

Here is a simplified code:

connect.py:

```
import paramiko


HOST = "test.example.com"
USER = "test"
KEY = "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

def test_ssh():
  try:
      ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER, key_filename=KEY)
  except Exception as e:
      raise ValueError("Connection Error: {}".format(str(e)))
      ssh.close()

def run_ssh(cmd, logname):
  file = open(logname, 'w')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
  for line in iter(stdout.readline, ''):
    file.write(''.join(line))
  file.close()
  ssh.close()
```

app.py:

```
import threading
from flask import jsonify
from connect import test_ssh, run_ssh
import time

min2 ='/home/test/2min.sh'
log2 = '2minuteoutput.log'
min5 ='/home/test/5min.sh'
log5 = '5minuteoutput.log'

def run(cmd, logname):
  try:
    test_ssh()
  except ValueError as e:
    return jsonify({"status": "error", 'message' : str(e)})
  else:
    somethread = threading.Thread(target=run_ssh, args=(cmd, logname))
    somethread.start()

run(min2, log2)
time.sleep(5)
run(min5, log5)
```

On another host, I place 2 shell scripts which I am executing:

/home/test/2min.sh (owned by test user and with executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting 2 minute job at: "`date`
sleep 60
echo "2min job min1" `date`
sleep 60
echo "2min job min2" `date`
echo "Completed 2 minute job at:" `date`
```

/home/test/5min.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting 5 minute job at: "`date`
sleep 60
echo " 5 min job: min1" `date`
sleep 60
echo "5min job: min2" `date`
sleep 60
echo "5 min job: min3" `date`
sleep 60
echo "5min job min4" `date`
sleep 60
echo "5min job min5" `date`
echo "Completed 5 minute job at:" `date`
```

Then I execute it as python app.py and the output logs look like this:

2minuteoutout.log:

```
Starting 2 minute job at: Tue Apr 30 20:09:06 UTC 2019
2min job min1 Tue Apr 30 20:10:06 UTC 2019
2min job min2 Tue Apr 30 20:11:06 UTC 2019
Completed 2 minute job at: Tue Apr 30 20:11:06 UTC 2019
```

5minuteoutput.log:

```
Starting 5 minute job at: Tue Apr 30 20:09:11 UTC 2019
 5 min job: min1 Tue Apr 30 20:10:11 UTC 2019
```

Both jobs were ended at 20:11:06 UTC when ssh.close() was called from the first job.

Also here is the output of paramiko debug log:

```
DEB [20190430-21:20:26.906] thr=1   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xd6ed09b0
DEB [20190430-21:20:26.907] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.4.2
DEB [20190430-21:20:26.996] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
INF [20190430-21:20:26.997] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.085] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.085] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.085] thr=1   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.085] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.085] thr=1   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha1
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.086] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.215] thr=1   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.216] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.216] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for test.example.com: 
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.217] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.299] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20190430-21:20:27.399] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.400] thr=3   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.484] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.484] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.604] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.604] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.683] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20190430-21:20:27.767] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.491] thr=4   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0xd14075c0
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.492] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.4.2
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.579] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
INF [20190430-21:20:32.579] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: kex algos:['curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Kex agreed: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: MAC agreed: hmac-sha1
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.667] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Compression agreed: none
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.756] thr=4   paramiko.transport: kex engine KexNistp256 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.757] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.758] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Trying discovered key in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.841] thr=4   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20190430-21:20:32.932] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEB [20190430-21:20:32.933] thr=5   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.016] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.016] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.137] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.138] thr=4   paramiko.transport: Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.224] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20190430-21:20:33.310] thr=4   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEB [20190430-21:22:27.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEB [20190430-21:22:27.780] thr=1   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
```

What I gathered from log - it looks like paramiko.transport is already using threads. Also if I am reading this correctly(?) - it opens 1 channel.
It is listed as opened twice (for each script - once at 21:20:27 and then at 21:20:33). However both of those are called chan 0, so it might then be the same chanel reused? 
Once ssh.close() is issued from the first job that 1 channel is closed. This kind of makes sense as it already has an active connection to the same server, so might as well reuse it. 
I did try using a channel as well, but got the same result;

From this it seems that I might need to figure out a way to launch/force multiple channels - this would be hard to do interactively, and with some type of loop it might open unused channels for every call and would require logic to send next calls to this other channel.

I want to make sure that the app I am working on is fully capable of handling multiple tasks at the same time, so I wanted to pose this question and see whether anybody more familiar with paramiko might be able to provide me with some pointers - any help is much appreciated!

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: Hi Martin - thank you for looking into this; I have just edited my posting, so as to include a fully working and verifiable example. I suspect that maybe I should switch to using chanel , though I don't have much experience with paramiko and was wondering if maybe there is an easier way to make Paramiko client somehow work around this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my issue was with sharing the 'ssh' object in connect.py between test_ssh and run_ssh functions. I thought I've tested this already but apparently not.

To make sure there is no confusion I have named them differently too, and place them within functions as in:

```
def test_ssh():
  sshtest = paramiko.SSHClient()
  sshtest.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  try:
      sshtest.connect(HOST, username=USER, key_filename=KEY)
  except Exception as e:
      raise ValueError("Connection Error: {}".format(str(e)))
      sshtest.close()
  finally:
      sshtest.close()

def run_ssh(cmd, logname):
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect(HOST, username=USER, key_filename=KEY)
  file = open(logname, 'w')
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
  for line in iter(stdout.readline, ''):
    file.write(''.join(line))
  file.close()
  ssh.close()
```

With this code everything works as expected.